# Erro com acentuação no email do laravel

Tags: laravel

No arquivo `.env` da minha aplicação em Laravel defini um nome padrão para envio de e-mail por exemplo: `MAIL_FROM_NAME='Registro Jurídico'` e na caixa de entrada chega `Registro Jur?dicdico`, o que posso fazer para corrigir isso? Utilizo Laravel 5.4

Comment: Experimenta utilizar &iacute; no lugar de í, se não for, verifica qual é o encoding do seu .env (abre ele pelo Notepad++ e olha no rodapé o encoding)

Comment: Deu certo, valeu Guilherme.